# c# how to - post to facebook user wall with 'facebook username' and 'facebook password'

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i wanna write a c# wpf application for end user, where the user can post messages including a picture to HIS facebook wall, like 'hi, is use a funny program for writing to my wall'.

of course, several different user on several different computers should use my program and i think the on and only setup should be the users 'facebook username' and 'facebook password', BUT i can not find the way to do that. :(

yes i found the way to get a access token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/oauth/access_token?client_id=[foo]&client_secret=[bar]&grant_type=client_credentials
```

and how i can get the permissions for a user account

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/[client id]/permissions?access_token=[bar foo]
```

but i can not believe that the user must give my application over a complicated way access to his account via a facebook website! is there not way via 'facebook username' and 'facebook password'???

i am searching since hours, but i can not find a solution, so maybe someone has a link our tip for me? thx

Comment: NEVER EVER ask users for their username and password. authorize users to get an access token (in that case, with the publish_actions permission) and use that one to post. there is no other way. also, no intelligent user would enter his facebook password on a page/app that is not from facebook.

Comment: No there is no way using a username and password because it is against Facebook Terms of Service and Facebook Platform Policy to share password or ask for password.

Comment: ok i understand, thx for the info.